# Reduce lines of code in function to read files in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to cut the lines of this code and I do not see how the code I show is the minimum of lines that could achieve:

```
function read_file(FileName: String): AnsiString;
var
  F: File;
  Buffer: AnsiString;
  Size: Integer;
  ReadBytes: Integer;
  DefaultFileMode: Byte;
begin
  Result := '';
  DefaultFileMode := FileMode;
  FileMode := 0;
  AssignFile(F, FileName);
  Reset(F, 1);

  if (IOResult = 0) then
  begin
    Size := FileSize(F);
    while (Size > 1024) do
    begin
      SetLength(Buffer, 1024);
      BlockRead(F, Buffer[1], 1024, ReadBytes);
      Result := Result + Buffer;
      Dec(Size, ReadBytes);
    end;
    SetLength(Buffer, Size);
    BlockRead(F, Buffer[1], Size);
    Result := Result + Buffer;
    CloseFile(F);
  end;

  FileMode := DefaultFileMode;
end;
```

is there any way to reduce more lines?

Comment: You have two nearly identical SetLength / BlockRead / concat blocks. You can turn them into one. Not sure whether it will be shorter in the number of lines, but it will definitely be better from code design point of view.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as off-topic because it's requesting improvements to working code, so it belongs on Code Review

Comment: I don't think it will be shorter, but you can use the Win32 API functions (CreateFile, ReadFile, etc.) as an alternative. That would prevent cross platform portability, but is the most direct way to do it.

Comment: @Jens The Win32 functions are named CreateFile and ReadFile and CloseHandle and GetFileSizeEx.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I just realized that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using old-style I/O, the following function is probably the smallest one you can do and still handle errors appropriately (if appropriately handling errors is to return an empty string).

```
function read_file(const FileName: String): AnsiString;
var
  F: File;
  DefaultFileMode: Byte;
begin
  DefaultFileMode := FileMode;
  try
    FileMode := 0;
    AssignFile(F, FileName);
    {$I-}
    Reset(F, 1);
    {$I+}
    if IoResult=0 then
      try
        SetLength(Result,FileSize(F));
        if Length(Result)>0 then begin
          {$I-}
          BlockRead(F,Result[1],LENGTH(Result));
          {$I+}
          if IoResult<>0 then Result:='';
        end;
      finally
        CloseFile(F);
      end;
  finally
    FileMode := DefaultFileMode;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: perfect , if I delete the "{ $ I- }" the code stops working? , Because if there are comments or something binding in the code ...

thanks for the help

Comment: The {$I-} turns off the runtime library's I/O checking (so you have to do it yourself, using IoResult), until the following {$I+}. Thus the _Reset(F,1)_ and _BlockRead(F,....);_ will not terminate the program with a runtime error in case they fail, but will return the error code for you to check via the IoResult function.

Comment: It's easier and cleaner to do it as per my answer and avoid the test for length being zero. That's what the Pointer(Result)^ is all about. It is safe even when range checking is enabled.

Comment: I didn't want to get too creative with my answer, as the OP is obviously not too experienced.

Comment: Besides - passing NIL to BlockRead (which is a direct mapping to ReadFile Win32 API, IIRC) - is not (as I read the documentation) officially supported, and the fact that it works is simply blind luck... It might just as well stop working in Windows 12.

Comment: Where does the documentation say that?

Comment: Where does it say that NIL is an acceptable value? The documentation states that "_This buffer must remain valid for the duration of the read operation_" - is NIL a _valid_ value? Where does it say that it _is_? The mere fact that it doesn't mention what happens when NIL is passed is reason enough (in my book) not to do it... You have absolutely _zero_ guarantee that this behaviour won't be changed in a newer Windows version...

Comment: The buffer must be able to hold `nNumberOfBytesToRead`. And when `nNumberOfBytesToRead` is zero, any value for `lpBuffer` is fine. It would be a bug in `ReadFile` if `ReadFile` ever de-referenced `lpBuffer` when `nNumberOfBytesToRead`. That's the way I read the documentation.

Comment: You read it your way - I read it my way. Since there's no mention of what _does_ happens when NIL is passed, I believe the most prudent form of action is to avoid it. YMMV... And I'm not talking about de-referencing the buffer, but merely that the function could easily implement a safeguard to prevent NIL pointer being passed at the front instead of catching it via an exception later on in the process. In most (all?) other cases of the Win32 documentation, it is explicitly stated when NIL is an acceptable value. Here, it is not. My conclusion: It is not (officially) an acceptable value...

Comment: We disagree. I'm confident that NULL is fine in that scenario.

Comment: Then we must agree to disagree...

Comment: This doesn't "handle errors appropriately", it **hides** them. What's more, because reading `IOResult` is a "destructive" operation, any potentially useful information about an error (if one did occur) is gone.

Comment: Hence my "(if appropriately handling errors is to return an empty string)", which is what the OP's original function did...

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
function read_file(const FileName: String): AnsiString;
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
  try
    SetLength(Result, Stream.Size);        
    Stream.ReadBuffer(Pointer(Result)^, Stream.Size);
   finally
     Stream.Free;
   end;
 end;
```

In modern Delphi the `TFile` class has static methods that can do this as a one liner. Although not directly into an `AnsiString`.

As well as being shorter I perceive the following additional benefits:

1. Avoiding Pascal I/O in favour of modern streams.
2. Error handling by exceptions, taken care of by the stream class.
3. A single allocation of the string variable as opposed to repeated inefficient re-allocations.

If you must do this with Pascal I0 use a single allocation.

```
SetLength(Buffer, FileSize(F));
BlockRead(F, Pointer(Result)^, Length(Result), ReadBytes);
```

Comment: there is no way to use your code without "classes" ?

Comment: You want to avoid using the Classes unit? Why so? If you are dead set on pascal io allocate the entire string once and read with a single call to BlockRead.

Comment: because it is a console application in which I do not want so much weight , sorry for not rinse it before .

Comment: It's a bit late now isn't it. Anyway, do what I said in my last comment.

Comment: @Test123 Since your result will be a AnsiString of the complete size of the file there is no need to read the file in chunks, but if the file can get big, you might want to rethink the overall design of returning one big AnsiString.

Comment: ok david , i understand

Comment: @Test The main point is to allocate once and read once. I've shown you how to do that both for streams and pascal IO. Do you really not use any unit beyond System and SysUtils?

Comment: If you really want to access the whole file content in memory, and deal with large files, consider using a **memory-mapped file view** via `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()`